# page view is not as desired, html not appearing, page is blank

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a pop up window appearing after a file is uploaded,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript (Me.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:
   window.open ('http://rsspl05/DocAdmin/confirmmsg.aspx?tdnum=" & TDnum &
   "','mywindow','width=800,height=400,location=no');", True)
```

but the pop up which I get is a blank page with Page Source:

```
<!-- beginning of HttpRedirect.htm file -->

<script type="text/javascript">

function redirectToHttps()     
{     
  var httpURL = window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname;     
  var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL ;     
  window.location = httpsURL ;     
}     
redirectToHttps();     
</script>

<!-- end of HttpRedirect.htm file -->
```

and the actual aspx code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Confirmmsg.aspx.vb" Inherits="docadmin_Confirmmsg" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Technical Documents</title>

<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function confirmmsg(val)
{
//    // alert(val + ' has been uploaded successfully.');
//    
     //if(confirm("Do you want to upload another document?")==true){
     //   window.location.href="UploadDoc.aspx";
     ///}else{
     // window.location.href="../Search.aspx";
    // } 
      self.close();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align:center">
    The document has been successfully uploaded.The link to the document:<asp:HyperLink
            ID="lnkpath" runat="server" Target="_blank"  Visible="false">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
      <br /><asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="OK" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of the following few things:

- You are calling the correct url/file
- Your aspx page is inheriting the correct codebehind file
- Check that there is nothing in your popup codebehind file that will cause the issue
- Double check the final(incorrect) popup url to see if it is the file you called, if it redirected to something else, trace/debug your process flow to see what can cause it.

This is just a very generic options, so let me know if you find something. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

That page is a redirect to the https page (rather than the http) - is your server configured to only serve https?  maybe the url http://rsspl05/DocAdmin/confirmmsg.aspx should be https://rsspl05/DocAdmin/confirmmsg.aspx